# Is there any way I could debug Python and C++ together?

Tags: python, c++, linux, debugging, ide

I was doing a project that is mainly using C++ with Python embedded on it using pybind11, and this project was designed to run in Linux environment. Currently I was using Visual Studio Code, as it supports development in WSL. But the problem I faced was that I can't debug C++ and Python together, I can only add breakpoints and debug the C++, but can't do the same thing on the Python.

I was aware of VScode can [debug Python with C++ extension](https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/), but I was using C++ with python embedded to it. I also knew that Visual Studio can support [mixed mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), but unfortunately it does not support developing in WSL.

Is there any IDE that I can debug C++ with Python, and support development in Linux at the same time? IDE that can run in Linux would be better. This problem has been struggling me for a long time, hope I can get some ideas from here.

Comment: Interesting problem. Normally the debugger that owns the process does the debugging and probably won't understand the alternate languages well enough to give you a detailed view of the execution. But Python is weird. Any chance that pybind spins up a python interpreter that you can attach a debugger in a second IDE to?